# Which dependency add to Eclipse jave project for fix javax.xml.rpc.Service issue?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, rpc

I have creating web sevice client.

```
import javax.xml.rpc.Stub;
```

produces error:

```
The import javax.xml.rpc cannot be resolved
```

What lib I should add?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried j2ee.jar or something similar,

you can check here for the full list:
[jar finder](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/javax.xml.rpc.Stub)